# unboundlocalerror after 30min of running

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error, unbound

my program is running just fine for some time, could be 5min of 30min. Then I get an error

I'm really puzzeled. The code runs fine for a while, Once I measured 5min, once 35min. The code on which I get the error is called every 30sec or so, so it is not the first time it is called. It gets the data from a sensor and prints it. There is no other variable anywhere in the program called DP

```
class sensor():
    class DP_sensor():
        def __init__(self,USB_port):
        # definitions for USB0 serial for dust particle sensor
            self.ser = serial.Serial()
            #ser.port = sys.argv[1]
            self.ser.port = USB_port
            self.ser.baudrate = 9600
            self.ser.open()
            self.ser.flushInput()

        def dp_process_frame(self, d):
            r = struct.unpack('<HHxxBBB', d[2:])
            pm25 = r[0]/10.0
            pm10 = r[1]/10.0
            checksum = sum(v for v in d[2:8])%256
            print("PM 2.5: {} μg/m^3  PM 10: {} μg/m^3 CRC={}".format(pm25, pm10, "OK" if (checksum==r[2] and r[3]==0xab) else "NOK"))
            return pm25

        def dp_sensor_read(self):
            byte = 0x0
            while byte != b'\xaa':
                byte = self.ser.read(size=1)
            d = self.ser.read(size=10)
            if d[0] == 0xc0:
                DP=self.dp_process_frame(byte + d)
            return DP
```

This is the error message, I would expect a message like this only at the first run...

```
  File "/home/pi/AirQuality/AirQual_v03classes.py", line 75, in dp_sensor_read
    return DP
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'DP' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Here's a hint: what happens if `d[0] != 0xc0`?  Welcome to Stack Overflow btw! I recommend taking the [tour].

Comment: Please check out [mre]. I was able to reproduce the issue in 5 lines of code. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/wjandrea/2324b6c161fb440ec67c8aad0ba15683).

Comment: @wjandrea
mmm, that is indeed an error, but 0xC0 should never happen, it's left -over from another approach. But I will remove it and see if it solves the issue, you might very well be right